# Renewcommand footnoterule only in a single page

Tags: footnotes

Is it possible to use `\renewcommand\footnoterule{}` for a single page only ?

In other words, taken into account that separators are already set in pages 1-3, can I remove the footnote separator on my fourth page and set it again in my fifth page ?

Actually, I found some codes using the bigfoot/manyfoot packages, but they did not really help me to get what I want...

Answer (score 2):

The footnote rule is typeset when the page number is already known. You can modify the definition of `\footnoterule` to do nothing when the page number is 4, taking advantage to the fact that the rule actually takes up no vertical space on the page.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,paperwidth=3in,margin=1.3cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnoterule{
  \ifnum\c@page=4 \else
    \kern-3\p@
    \hrule \@width 2in \kern 2.6\p@ % the \hrule is .4pt high
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

a\footnote{a}\clearpage
b\footnote{b}\clearpage
c\footnote{c}\clearpage
d\footnote{d}\clearpage
e\footnote{e}

\end{document}
```

[image]

How to have a list of pages where not to use `\footnoterule`? Here's a way.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

% just to get smaller pictures
\usepackage[paperheight=4cm,paperwidth=3in,margin=1.3cm]{geometry}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% keep the original \footnoterule
\cs_new_eq:NN \guillaume_footnoterule: \footnoterule
% redefine \footnoterule
\cs_set_protected:Npn \footnoterule
 {
  \bool_set_true:N \l_guillaume_footnoterule_bool
  \seq_map_function:NN \g_guillaume_footnoterule_pages_seq \guillaume_test:n
  \bool_if:NT \l_guillaume_footnoterule_bool { \guillaume_footnoterule: }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \guillaume_test:n
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1 = \value{page} }
   {
    \seq_map_break:n { \bool_set_false:N \l_guillaume_footnoterule_bool }
   }
 }
% save the list of pages where not to have a footnoterule
\seq_new:N \g_guillaume_footnoterule_pages_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\nofootnoterule}{m}
 {
  \seq_gset_from_clist:Nn \g_guillaume_footnoterule_pages_seq { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\nofootnoterule{1,3,4}

\begin{document}

a\footnote{a}\clearpage
b\footnote{b}\clearpage
c\footnote{c}\clearpage
d\footnote{d}\clearpage
e\footnote{e}

\end{document}
```

The command `\nofootnoterule` populates a sequence and at the moment when `\footnoterule` is called by the kernel, the current page number is checked against the sequence.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @egreg. Actually, is it possible to add a OR condition to the \ifnum statement ? I.e. is it possible to specify a set of page (like \ifnum page=1 OR page=3, for instance) rather than a single page ?

Comment: @GuillaumeC. Yes, it's possible, I've just added some code.

Comment: This solved my issues. Thanks @egreg !